# Domain Access permissions issue

Tags: 7, nodes, domain-access

I am having an issue with Domain Access in Drupal 7.

The admin user (and seemingly any user I add to the system) is unable to edit content attached to any child domains on the site.  The main domain is fine, but all others on the same site is effected.

When I attempt to edit content on the Admin (or other user) I get:

> You are not authorized to access this page.

I can view all content with no problem.

How do I fix these permissions issues?

The following is the screenshot of the permissions implemented by the module.

[image: screenshot]

The "Bypass content access control" permission is disabled for all roles including the "Administrator" one; no other access module is enabled. Two Domains have been set up, the primary one and a sub-domain, which shares some content and has its own. Two languages are enabled for each domain (English and French) using the i18n module.
The "Edit any content on assigned domains," and "Delete any content on assigned domains" permissions are set, but the users still cannot edit the content.

Comment: Did you check the issue list http://drupal.org/project/issues/domain?text=permission&status=Open&priorities=All&categories=bug&version=7.x&component=All  and documentation http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/domain especially http://drupal.org/node/1096972 ? What Domain Access version do you have installed ?

Comment: Ive been reviewing the documentation, as far as I can tell I am compliant. however it seems to not be working.

See screenshot of access perms: http://imgur.com/HUhk2

Domain Access version: 7.x-2.18 / D version: 7.12

Comment: Hmm I seem to have figured out that If I log out and go to /user/login on the domain i want to edit content on, and login to the site from there, I have the ability to edit the content from that domain but nothing else. (even though the account should have access on all domains) - 

I am not complaining, but it does seem rather roundabout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are logged in at your maindomain and want to edit content on the other domains, you have to enable the`$cookie_domain = '.yourmaindomain.com';` in your settings.php.
It is also described in this video [domain acess video](http://archive.org/details/SharingcontentacrossmultiplesiteswithDomainAccess)

Answer (score 1):

Hi try to configure this setting
http://yoursite.tld/admin/structure/domain/roles